# Update function not working in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-edittext

currently I am doing my final year project using Android Studio. There is few function left to complete my mobile application.

However, my application didn't performed update function.

Before proceed with update account in my mobile application, I'm using JSON to extract the value in database. Then the value is store in the EditText of the update form. Then I've tried to make some changes in the form. When I clicked the submit button, it will proceed to the next activity which is view account. But, the value that I've make some changes is still same as before update account. I've already checked the coding or the passing value in Intent, but nothing wrong. Why this is occur? Can anyone help me with this?

I'm totally lost where to start. I'm still basic in developing Android application.

I'm using PHP and MySQL to update the value in the database.

Here is my coding in PHP.

```
    <?php

$response = array();

        include 'db_connect.php';
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();      if (isset($_POST['idDoc'])) {

        $idDoc = $_POST['idDoc'];   $namedoc = $_POST['namedoc'];
        $ic = $_POST['ic'];     $address = $_POST['address'];   $notel = $_POST['notel'];   $passwrd = $_POST['passwrd'];

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `DOCTOR` SET namedoc = '$namedoc', ic = '$ic', address = '$address', noTel = '$notel', passwrd = '$passwrd' WHERE idDoc = $idDoc");  // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully updated
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Account successfully updated.";

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {

        } } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        echo json_encode($response);   
 } ?>
```

Here is the code for update the value in the EditText.

```
 class updAcc extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(updateAccDoc.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating accound..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            String namedoc = nameDoc.getText().toString();
            String iddoc = idDoc.getText().toString();
            String icdoc = icDoc.getText().toString();
            String address = addDoc.getText().toString();
            String notel = notelDoc.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idDoc", iddoc));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namedoc", namedoc));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ic", icdoc));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notel", notel));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwrd", pass));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(urll2,
                    "POST", param);

            try {

                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent intent = new Intent(updateAccDoc.this, docProfile.class);
                    String ID6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idDoc");
                    intent.putExtra("idDoc", ID6);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

The trace said "Cannot convert String to JSON"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to handle the response of your http request in the doInBackground method instead of returning the response, Which will allow you use the response in the onPostExecute method.
check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for proper usage of AsyncTask.

Add `return json;` After `JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(urll2,"POST", param);` then cut your try block from the doInBackground method and paste it in the onPostExecute method.

onPostExecute should look like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
       int success = json.getInt("success");

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully updated
            Intent intent = new Intent(updateAccDoc.this, docProfile.class);
            String ID6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idDoc");
            intent.putExtra("idDoc", ID6);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            // failed to update product
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```